# Can I award user with special bounty after accepting his anwer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496065/why-is-this-lr1-grammar-not-lalr1), and I haven't start a bounty for this question.
After I got my answer I'd like to give a user a special bounty, because I consider his answer very helpful and it saved me a lot of time. I've already accepted the answer. Is there a way how can I give him some bounty?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just click "start a bounty", choose bounty amount and select the **Reward existing answer** reason.
Refer to the [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for the details.

Comment: I expected something like that, but ... I guess it will appear 2 days after asking? Am I right?

Comment: @JanVorcak Sure. Here is the quotation from the topic I mentioned: `A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.`